# tensorflow: is there a way to specify XLA_GPU with tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

following code is used to specify device on which tf node is running on

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
  a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
```

i have already known:
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52943489/11170845), [tensorflow doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/xla/overview) and [xla demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax_xla.py)

what i want to know is:

is there a way to specify XLA_GPU as the device on which tf node is running on

```
with tf.device('/XLA_GPU:0'):
  a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
```

executing the code above gives `ValueError: Unknown attribute: 'device' in '/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:/XLA_GPU:0'`

this is 100% reproducible on google colab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try 'device:XLA_GPU:0'

```
with tf.device('device:XLA_GPU:0'):
  a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
```